# Change default "open with" on remote files in Ubuntu nautilus

Tags: nautilus, sftp, default-programs

Whenever I browse a folder in nautilus that is connected via `sftp` and click on whatever file, it opens with **KeePassXC** instead of **gedit**.

For local files, I can right click > Properties > Open with and set defaults. When browsing in `sftp` folders, the `open with` tab does not exist. This happens especially on files without a file extension. `file.txt` opens in gedit by default. `post-receive` on the other hand opens in KeePassXC

How can I edit the default GUI Editor for remote files?

Comment: It seems like the file you're trying to open might  have an unrecognized mime-type, or something is causing the OS not to realize it may be open with `gedit`. While your share is still mounted, open a terminal and `cd` to that directory. Use the `file` command on your file, and check what type is it. Also, while using the terminal, try opening that file with `gedit` using the terminal command: `gedit my_file`. Did it open without any error messages?

Comment: Hi @Pizza, it recognizes the files as `application/octet-stream`. `gedit post-receive` in the local terminal in remote folder opens the file as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our comments session:

It seems like the file you are trying to open is not a `text` file, thus the output of the `file` command resulted a mime type of `application/octet-stream`.

 From your question I assume it is an output of a web-request or something similar.

Coincidentally, it seems like you already have an installed app which chose for you to open such files using it by default: `KeePassXC` in your case.

A simple solution for your "no right mouse button" would be to open the file using `gedit` from the terminal:

```
gedit your_file
```

**Another option** would be to choose a new default app using a terminal command, but you have to make sure it won't affect your `KeePassXC` program, or to remember that from now on `KeePassXC` will not be the default app for `application/octet-stream` type files:

Using the command `mimeopen`, we'll configure a new default app:

```
mimeopen -d your_file
```

The output would be a prompt asking you to **choose a new default app**, for example:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type application/octet-stream

    1) LibreOffice Writer  (libreoffice-writer)
    2) Text Editor  (org.gnome.gedit)
    3) Kate  (org.kde.kate)
    4) Vim  (vim)
    5) Visual Studio Code  (code_code)
    6) Other...

use application #
```

If you do not see `gedit` on your list, press `Other...`, and a new prompt will appear, requesting an app name (must be correctly typed).

```
use command:
```

Type `gedit` and you're all set !

**Edit:** In case the default app still did not change, it means that there is a priority conflict, and we'll need to set the priority manually.

The command `mimeopen` updates the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file, and adds our selection in that list.

 Using the command `gedit ~/.config/mimeapps.list`, let's manually edit this file and move our selection from `[Added Associations]` to `[Default Applications]`.

**note:** remove the `;` character when copying your matching line from `[Added Associations]` to `[Default Applications]`

Comment: Thank you. Opening in terminal is a lot more work than double clicking (or even `right click > Open with other Application > ...`). I also tried `mimeopen -d post-receive` and it opened once in gedit. I also tried updating `usr/share/applications/defaults.list` with `application/octet-stream=application/octet-stream;` - nothing helps. Please note: locally the file suggests `Run` as default for double clicking. Also annoying. But is is correctly identified as `shell script (application/x-shellscript)` and not as `octet-stream`.

Comment: In this case it is a matter of priority and how `mimeopen` worked for you. The command `mimeopen` updated the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file, and adds your selection when using this command. Let's manually edit this file, and move our selection from `[Added Associations]` to `[Default Applications]`. Use  `gedit ~/.config/mimeapps.list` - **note:** remove the `;` character when copying your line from  `[Added Associations]` to `[Default Applications]`.

Comment: you sir, are a linux wizard and genius. Indeed within `~./config/mimeapps.list` the type `application/octet-stream` was associated with KeepassXC. Added gedit and it works. Would you mind updating your answer to help others too? Maybe as Step 3?

Comment: Of course, glad to hear it worked for you :)

Comment: @Pizza Thank you for this. **EDIT: I figured it out! Don't worry.** It works perfectly for me, with one exception: `.htaccess`. Nautilus correctly opens a local `.htaccess` in gedit, but insists on opening an sftp `.htaccess` in KeePassXC. Do you know how I can fix this? I don't have enough knowledge to figure out which entry in `mimeapps.list` I need to change. Thank you.